# unable to find & configure usb adapter

Tags: linux, usb, bluetooth, arch-linux, bluez

I got a new Bluetooth adapter (from plugable, model USB-BT4LE) that states it would work with Linux kernels 3.0.34 and higher and I'm running 5.2.2 with arch. I installed `bluez` and `bluez-utils` but the Bluetooth Adapter application says "No Bluetooth adapters have been found." while I get

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   13.787662] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   13.787677] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.787681] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.787682] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.787685] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   14.135558] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[   14.136551] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[   14.152549] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[   14.153553] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[   14.248731] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2
[   14.248735] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
```

it seems like something is recognized but how can I configure it (and connect my devices)?

Thanks!

**Update**:

After plugging in the adapter, I see the following in dmesg:

```
[ 7783.692990] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2
[ 7783.692993] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
[ 7788.617982] audit: type=1131 audit(1581476791.719:133): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

Based on https://support.plugable.com/t/need-bcm20702a1-0a5c-21e8/8803/2 searched for firmware on the computer. `$ sudo find / -name "*BCM2070*"` unfortunately does not yield any results, either.

I found https://www.linuxsecrets.com/2840-enable-bluetooth-on-linux which basically instructs to download https://s3.amazonaws.com/plugable/bin/fw-0a5c_21e8.hcd and store it in `/lib/firmware/brcm/` which I did, I replugged the dongle and got:

```
[ 8545.828783] usb 4-1.8: new full-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
[ 8545.933009] usb 4-1.8: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e8, bcdDevice= 1.12
[ 8545.933013] usb 4-1.8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 8545.933015] usb 4-1.8: Product: BCM20702A0
[ 8545.933017] usb 4-1.8: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[ 8545.933019] usb 4-1.8: SerialNumber: 5CF370984D12
[ 8545.981571] audit: type=1130 audit(1581477549.083:146): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-rfkill comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[ 8546.044020] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[ 8546.045016] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[ 8546.061014] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[ 8546.061981] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[ 8546.904154] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1338
[ 8546.920998] Bluetooth: hci0: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
```

in `dmesg` which looks good but this still hangs:

```
$ bluetoothctl 
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

and when I open `Bluetooth Adapters` from my K-Menu, it still says: "No Bluetooth adapters have been found."

Hmm, `lsusb` gives me this:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 028: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 004 Device 025: ID 1004:631c LG Electronics, Inc. G2/Optimus Android Phone [MTP mode]
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c215 Logitech, Inc. Extreme 3D Pro
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it,

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
```

showed me that the bluetooth service isn't running on my machine, so I started it with

```
$ sudo systemctl start bluetooth
```

and making sure it gets enabled after a reboot, I also id a:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

now it shows my adapter!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get your firmware from here if you can't find it.

https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm